# With jQuery, how to find an data attribute on or within an element? (tree traversal)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have several unknown elements (Could be span, input, select, div, whatever):

```
<div id="SomeControl" >  <-- Data Attribute could be here
  <span>  <-- or Data Attribute could be here or even lower in the DOM
    ...  somewhere here is a data attribute: data-is-dirty="True"
   </span>
</div>
```

...

```
var $myControl = $('#SomeControl');
```

Using $myControl is there a way to find the existence and/or value of a given data attribute?

I've tried:

```
 var isDirty = $myControl.find(':has([data-is-dirty]').data('is-dirty');
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `.find('[data-is-dirty]')`?

Comment: You really are better off doing it in two steps. It can be done in one line, but it is bad.

Comment: This works but I don't like it: var isDirty =  $myControl.parent().find('[data-is-dirty]').data('is-dirty'); because you can't have the control in the same element.

Comment: @Rodney why not? What could be a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var isDirty = $myControl.find('[data-is-dirty]');
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/UpGQX/1/ Courtesy: gibberish

To select `$myControl` itself (if dirty):

```
var isDirty = $myControl.find('[data-is-dirty]');
var myControlIsDirty = $myControl.attr('data-is-dirty');
if (typeof myControlIsDirty !== 'undefined' && myControlIsDirty !== false) {
   isDirty.push($myControl);
}
```

or maybe even better:

```
var isDirty = $myControl.parent().find('[data-is-dirty]');
```

Comment: Your solution works. +1 Perhaps you were downvoted because you didn't put a jsFiddle..? Anyway, here's one you can add to your answer - [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/UpGQX/1/)

Comment: @gibberish downvoted for not giving a fiddle even when my solution works? lol

Comment: Yes, I agree - you shouldn't have been downvoted (it wasn't by me!) Feel free to add the jsFiddle I created to your answer.

Comment: This does not work, it would fail if the first level has the dirty attribute! AKA if $myControl has it.

Comment: @Rodney even if attribute is at top just use .not()

Comment: @Rodney This works http://jsfiddle.net/T2MTa/3/ (see console). If this is not the correct answer then could you please explain your question a bit more?

Answer (score 3):

Ways I could think about doing it without wrapping it in another element. Not a fan of any of them, maybe it will inspire others.

```
var horrible1 = $("#test").find("*").andSelf().filter("[data-is-dirty]").length;

var horrible2 = $("#test").find("[data-is-dirty]").andSelf().filter("[data-is-dirty]").length;


var elem = $("#test");
var horrible3 = elem.parent().find("#" + elem.attr("id") + "[data-is-dirty], #" + elem.attr("id") + " [data-is-dirty]").length;

var elem = $("#test");
var horrible4 = elem.find("[data-is-dirty]").add(elem.filter("[data-is-dirty]")).length;

var horrible5 = $("[data-is-dirty]").filter( "#test, #test *" ).length;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Lc29/1/)

Answer (score 0):

`$( "[data='data-is-dirty']" )` , and if you want to exclude your parent div just use `.not("#SomeControl")`

try this http://fiddle.jshell.net/HHaT9/

Comment: Since you deleted the other one... `<div id="SomeControl" data-is-dirty>` is supposed to be matched.  You exclude it. That is the point of the question. It needs to match that and the children. It is a fun little question. And I am guessing you just downvoted me. ;)

Comment: do you want to include the parent or to exclude it ??

Comment: are you sure that you understood the question , if so please explain !

Answer (score 0):

```
var isDirty=$("#SomeControl[data-is-dirty],#SomeControl [data-is-dirty]").data('is-dirty');
```

[Edit] Same idea, if you don't know the element id:

```
var isDirty=$someControl.data("is-dirty")||$("[data-is-dirty]",$someControl).data("is-dirty");
```

Comment: I can't use the ID. I'm writing a custom user control where I don't have access to the ID. The user can set the ID to whatever they want.

Comment: @Rodney ok, I have rewritten the expression to use $someControl instead.